# Spring-Security 3.1 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthorizeTag

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsp-tags

I just upgraded from Spring Security 3.0.5 to 3.1.0.RC3

Now, the following JSP code gives me `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthorizeTag`

```
<security:authorize access="not hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')">
Welcome <%= request.getUserPrincipal().getName() %>
</security:authorize>
```

I look at the [Spring Security Reference Documentation 3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/taglibs.html#d0e6696) and it looks like the `<security:authorize>` tag should work. However when I look at the directory `org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz` in `spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RC3.jar` I cannot see any `AuthorizeTag.class` there.

What is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried digging the web with your exception?

Comment: Yes, no luck. I see in the 3.1 `org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz` directory `JspAuthorizeTag.class`, so I tried something like `<security:jspauthorize>` however Eclipse tells me there's not such tag. Also, looking at the class list http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/allclasses-noframe.html it seems like there's no such a class `AuthorizeTag`.

Comment: a request to rapt : please make @Simon answer correct so that other can find solution easily. for me also the same thing works.

Answer (score 28):

I found that Tomcat might cache the old security.tld, even the spring security library are all 3.1 version. Delete the Tomcat work directory and restart it would works fine now.

Comment: Yes the same, worked for me :)  (using eclipse : right click on Tomcat server / Clean Tomcat Work Directory)

Answer (score 2):

it is renamed to JspAuthorizeTag

(org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.JspAuthorizeTag)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have an old `security.tld` file somewhere. Make sure that you haven't copied it into your `WEB-INF` and that you don't have any old Spring Security jars in your classpath.

Comment: What is the meaning of having `JspAuthorizeTag.class` instead of `AuthorizeTag.class` in the taglibs jar?

Comment: @rapt: It means that they renamed that class. However, tag name defined in the [taglib definition file](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/taglibs/src/main/resources/META-INF/security.tld?r=94b78680392beaff6094ba149bd3677cb32658db) remains the same. So, if tag name is resolved to the old class, you should have an old taglib definition somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that an old `security.tld` could cause it, but I don't see how it could happen. I work with Eclipse Helios with Tomcat 6. I deleted all the 3.0.5 jars from `WEB-INF\lib` then dropped there all the new jars from the 3.1 security jar. The `spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RC3.jar` contains a directory `META-INF`, inside it there's the `security.tld` - this should have been enough to avoid my problem, right? --- Now mysteriously after I restarted tomcat from Eclipse 2 more times, `<security:authorize>` is starting again. Any idea why I had this problem then (I didn't change the app)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the security.tld (3.0.0.RELEASE):

```
<tag-class>org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthorizeTag</tag-class>
```

to

```
<tag-class>org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.JspAuthorizeTag</tag-class>
```

It's work for my configuration project with FreeMarker

```
<#assign security=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/tlds/security.tld"] />
```

(*mvn jetty:run* and *mvn tomcat:run*). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue in Spring MVC,

You need to add jar/dependency in pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
<version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding taglib jar file, you have to import package into your JSP file.

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.JspAuthorizeTag "%>
```

Please remove taglib Uri from your JSP file `<%@ taglib prefix="authz" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>`